# What does 30-day visa-free entry mean?

Tags: tourist-visas

Many countries offer 30-day visa-free travel. Does that mean that many days in a span of a year,  or does it  mean 30 days every visit, i.e. one may leave and come back for 30 days the next day?

Comment: Varies from one country to another. Could you edit your question to specify one country? Otherwise your question is too broad for this site.

Comment: Doing what you are suggesting is called a "visa run" and it will very quickly get picked up in most countries.

Answer (score 9):

For the cases I'm aware of, it's per visit.

However, you're absolutely not the first person to think that 30+30=60, 30+30+30=90, 30+30+... and immigration officers are wise to this. Some countries have formal policies: for example, the Schengen area restricts visa-free visitors to not more than 90 days in the area out of any period of 180 days. Other countries have less formal setups: the US, for example, will get twitchy about people trying to stay more than 90 days in any 180 even though it's not a literal rule. The US also demands that you leave North America between visa-free visits: it's not enough just to go to Canada or Mexico and back.

I suspect that any country will refuse entry if they get the impression that you're trying to string together multiple short-stay visits into a longer one. Doubly so if they think that, really, you're just trying to live there.  Remember that, in most cases, you have no *right* to visit foreign countries. If they have something like a 30-day visa-free visit scheme, that's not a guarantee that you'll be allowed in.